# Salesforce equivalent to sha256hex

Tags: apex, soap-api, soap, crypto, encryption

We are migrating services to salesforce and still need to access services via soap. We need a generated token in the soap header.

We need to mimic this algorithm in salesforce for the SOAP request:

```
org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex(String.valueOf(1403095886) + String.valueOf(1439404002329L) + "db6af2ad8e320b2b0e5684e89c8fcb02");
```

We currently have this:

```
String token = entityNumber + timeToken + salt;
Blob tokenBlob = Blob.valueOf(token);
Blob hashToken = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-256', tokenBlob);
```

How can we get the sha256hex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used this and it worked

```
String token = entityNumber + timeToken + salt;
Blob tokenBlob = Blob.valueOf(token);
Blob hashToken = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-256', tokenBlob);
String code = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(hashToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

String token = entityNumber + timeToken + salt;
Blob tokenBlob = Blob.valueOf(token);
Blob hashToken = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-256', tokenBlob);
String code = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(hashToken)